# Running unit tests from the command line fail after upgrading to Xcode 5.1

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

After upgrading to Xcode 5.1, running unit tests from the command line stopped working.

Here is what happens when I run `xcodebuild test -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug`

```
[...]
2014-03-11 15:32:08.392 Test Host[67583:907] Error loading /Users/0xced/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cdhjwjcbamuhpvfislepygilkusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Tests.xctest/MyApp Tests:  dlopen(/Users/0xced/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cdhjwjcbamuhpvfislepygilkusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Tests.xctest/MyApp Tests, 262): Library not loaded: /Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
  Referenced from: /Users/0xced/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cdhjwjcbamuhpvfislepygilkusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Tests.xctest/MyApp Tests
  Reason: image not found
IDEBundleInjection.c: Error loading bundle '/Users/0xced/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-cdhjwjcbamuhpvfislepygilkusg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Tests.xctest'
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

Although xcodebuild reports **** TEST SUCCEEDED ****, the tests clearly did not run.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error indicates that `/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest` is not found. So in order to fix it, I added a run script phase to my unit test target with the following script:

```
install_name_tool -change "/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest" "${SDKROOT}/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}"
```

It tells the unit test bundle to load the XCTest framework from the current SDK rather than from the `/Developer` directory which doesn’t exist.

Surprisingly, this fix was only needed on my machine but was not needed on our CI server. The differences between my machine and our CI server include respectively:

- Several Xcode versions (4.6.3 + 5.0.2 + 5.1) vs Xcode 5.1 only
- Several iOS simulators (6.1 + 7.1) vs iOS 7.1 simulator only